# Unable to go back to parent activity with toolbar back navigation in Android

Tags: android, android-activity, android-context

**Background**

I have two activities namely `MainActivity` and `AddPersion` respectively. I also have defined a java class namely `BaseActivity` which implements toolbar and menu items.

I want to move from `MainActivity` to `AddPerson` activity with the help of an Intent and then back to `MainActivity` by clicking the back navigation. I tried it by following this video:
[How to add Android Back Button](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FcPUFp8Qrps)

**Problem**

When I click on the back navigation button after moving to `AddPerson` nothing happens i.e I don't get moved back to `MainActivity`.

**Code**

*BaseActivity*

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

     private Context context; // tried Activity context too with no luck

     // code for onCreate here 
     // code for onCreateOptionsMenu here

     @Override
     public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){    

         switch (getItemId()){
            case R.id.share: 
                 // code for share here
                 break;                
            case R.id.addPerson: 
                 startActivity(new Intent(getContext(), AddPerson.class));
         }
         return true;
    }

    public void initToolbar(boolean isChild){

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(isChild);
    }

    public void setContext(Context context){ this.context = context; }
    public Context getContext(){  return context; }
}
```

*MainActivity*

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        initToolbar(false);
        setContext(this);
    }
}
```

*AddPerson*

```
public class AddPerson extends BaseActivity {

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_person);
        initToolbar(true);
     }
}
```

*AndroidManifest*

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".AddPerson"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

I know the problem is with context but I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public void initToolbar(Context from,Context to,boolean isChild){
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
   setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
   getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
   toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    startActivity(new 


  Intent(from,to)
     .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP));

}
});
}
```

And if you in AddPerson activity and want to go to Main activity you can call the function like this:

```
initToolbar(AddPerson.this,MainActivity.class,true);
```

and you can change to and from parameters depend on what you want.

Comment: shows error `AddPerson is not an enclosing class`. I don't want to use custom event listener,.

Comment: Do it in AddPerson itself;

Comment: I have defined `initToolbar` inside `BaseActivity` not in `AddPerson`.  In `AddPerson` I am only calling it.

Comment: So you need to add context as a parameter in every class, I'm gonna show u how in my another answer

Comment: shows error: `cannot resolve constructor 'Intent(android.content.Context, android.content.Context)`. I don't think its the right way. besides as I said I don't want to use event listener just the way I do it.

Answer (score 0):

In AddPerson Activity, you should override `onOptionsItemSelected()`
Using switch case, add a case for androi.R.id.home, and apply `onBackPressed()` .

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            onBackPressed();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't want to define `home` menu item. Just want to update the context of activity.